# Semi-supervised classification with R package 'upclass'

Tags: r, classification, data-mining

I have a question about the procedure of semi-supervised classification with R package 'upclass'.

The final purpose of this procedure is to label all of the data points that I own, and currently only small portion of my data is labeled and the rest of the data points are unlabeled. So, my plan is to label the entire data points using semi-supervised classification method.

What I know about semi-supervised classification is that I first need to do is to assign, let say, **60% of the labeled data points to training data** and **40% of the labeled data points to test data**. Also, as far as I know, I need to include **all of the unlabeled data points** into the **training data set**. Then, I can evaluate the model performance with the test data set which consists of only labeled data set.

My question is that how exactly the classification procedure should be. I have been reading the documentations about the 'upclass' package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/upclass/upclass.pdf and ftp://140.247.115.226/yum-rep/CRAN/web/packages/upclass/vignettes/upclass.pdf) and do not quite understand which command or which procedure is for training the model and which procedure is for testing the model.

In the first document (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/upclass/upclass.pdf), based on the description of the command, it looks that the command, 'upclassifymodel' in page 15-16, is used for semi-supervised classification. In the Usage of page 16, the 'cltest = null', which I think means that no labels are available for 'Xtest' data. (From the Arguments in page 8, 'Xtest' is unlabeled data).

(The 'upclassifymodel' code is as follows:):

```
upclassifymodel(Xtrain, cltrain, Xtest, cltest = NULL,modelName = "EEE", 
tol = 10^-5, iterlim = 1000, Aitken = TRUE, ...)
```

I am very confused this part, because then 'does the command with 'upclassifymodel' indicate only 'training step' or 'training and test step' both? I am very confused since, as far as I know, in the semi-supervised classification procedure, the unlabeled data set is included in training step and in the testing step, we only use labeled data set. Subsequently, if the command with 'upclassifymodel' is only for training model, then should we separately conduct the testing step using other validation processes?

In sum, my question is if the semi-supervised classification procedure that I think is appropriate (first, assign 60% labeled data and all unlabeled data to training data and 40% of labeled data to testing data, second, train the model with both labeled and unlabeled data set, and third test the model with 40% remaining labeled data.) and which R commands with 'upclass' package corresponds to the procedure. Ideally, I hope that somebody can put the entire code for the whole semi-supervised classification procedures using R 'upclass' package.

I am looking forward to your thoughts.

Comment: This looks more appropriate to either the statistics or (beta) data science forums. You are not actually asking a specific coding question but rather asking either for help designing an algorithm or for tutoring on an (obscure) package. You can flag it and ask a moderator to migrate it to the forum of you choice. I'm voting to close on SO and I predict 3 others will agree with me to make that will happen if migration doesn't happen soon.